# ArgumentNullException was unhandled, out of the blue

Tags: c#

I have been working on a project on and off, but I haven't touched it for 2 months, today I came back to it and I was unable to run it due to an error.

```
IEnumerable<MediaTitle> query = mediaTitleCollection.OfType<FilmMedia>();
```

The debugger stops on this line and gives the error described in title along with

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Its very frustrating since the code was working 100% before and now its dominated by this error. 
I have tried to clean the solution without much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) will raise an exception if the collection (`mediaTitleCollection`, in this case) is **null**.

> Its very frustrating since the code was working 100% before and now its dominated by this error. I have tried to clean the solution without much luck.

You should debug your application, and look for the location where `mediaTitleCollection` is supposed to be set.  It currently is being set to null or not being initialized properly.

Comment: I had double checked everything, but it seems that dropbox has been doing tricks on me while syncronizing. So my code was replaced with a wrong version. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'source' pointed in the exception message ?! Is it a field of FileMedia ?! Do you load the values from a data source like database ?